# 'Channels first' training accuracy very low compared to 'channels last'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mobilenet

## My issue:

I am trying to train a semantic segmentation model in tf.keras, in fact it works very well when I am using channels_last (WHC) mode (it reaches 96%+ val acc). **I wanted to train it in channels_first (CHW) mode** so the weights are compatible with TensorRT. When I do this, the ~80% **training accuracy in the first few epochs dips down** to around 0.020% and stays there permanently.

It is useful to know that the base of my model is a `tf.keras.applications.MobileNet()` model with the pre-trained 'imagenet' weights. **(Model architecture at the bottom.)**

### The transformation process:

I used the guidelines provided and I change only a few things here:

1. Set `tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format()` to 'channels_first'.
2. I change the channel order in the input tensor from: `input_tensor=Input(shape=(376, 672, 3))`  to: `input_tensor=Input(shape=(3, 376, 672))`
3. In my image preprocessing (using `tf.data.Dataset`), i use `tf.transpose(img, perm=[2, 0, 1])` on both my input image and one-hot encoded mask to change the channel orders. I checked this with equality assertion to make sure its correct and it seems to be fine.

When I change these the training starts fine but as I said the training accuracy goes down to almost zero. When I revert back everything's fine again.

### Possible leads:

What am I doing wrong or what could be the problematic part here? My suspicions are around these questions:

- *Are the pre-trained imageNet weights changed to the 'channels_first' order also when I set the backend? Is this something I should consider at all?*
- *Could it be that the `tf.transpose()` function messes up the mask's one-hot encoding? (I have 3 classes represented by 3 colors: lane, opposing lane, background)*

Maybe I am not seeing something obvious. I can provide further code and answers as needed.

### EDIT:

08/17: This is still an ongoing issue, I have tried several things:

- I checked if the image and the mask is correct after the transpose with numpy assertion, seems correct.
- I suspected that the loss function calculates on the wrong axis, so I customized the loss function for the first axis (where the channels are). Here it is:

```
def ReverseAxisLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=True, axis=1)
```

- My main suspicion is that the 'channels first' backend setting does nothing to transpose the pretrained 'imagenet' weights for the mobilenet part. Is there an updated way for TF2.x / Keras to transpose the pre-trained weights into CHW format?

**Here is the architecture** that I use (the `skipNet()` is the head network and the mobilenet is the base, and it is connected in the `create_model()` function)

```
def skipNet(encoder_output, feed1, feed2, classes):
    # random initializer and regularizer
    stddev = 0.01
    init = RandomNormal(stddev=stddev)

    weight_decay = 1e-3
    reg = l2(weight_decay)
   

    score_feed2 = Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 1), filters=classes, padding="SAME",
                kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=reg)(feed2)
    score_feed2_bn = BatchNormalization()(score_feed2)
    score_feed1 = Conv2D(kernel_size=(1, 1), filters=classes, padding="SAME",
                kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=reg)(feed1)
    score_feed1_bn = BatchNormalization()(score_feed1)

   

    upscore2 = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(4, 4), filters=classes, strides=(2, 2),
                               padding="SAME", kernel_initializer=init,
                               kernel_regularizer=reg)(encoder_output)
    height_pad1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((1,0),(0,0)))(upscore2)
    upscore2_bn = BatchNormalization()(height_pad1)

    fuse_feed1 = add([score_feed1_bn, upscore2_bn])

    upscore4 = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(4, 4), filters=classes, strides=(2, 2),
                               padding="SAME", kernel_initializer=init,
                               kernel_regularizer=reg)(fuse_feed1)
    height_pad2 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,0)))(upscore4)
    upscore4_bn = BatchNormalization()(height_pad2)

    fuse_feed2 = add([score_feed2_bn, upscore4_bn])

    upscore8 = Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=(16, 16), filters=classes, strides=(8, 8),
                               padding="SAME", kernel_initializer=init,
                               kernel_regularizer=reg, activation="softmax")(fuse_feed2)

    return upscore8

def create_model(classes):

    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(input_tensor=Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE),
                                                 include_top=False,
                                                 weights='imagenet')
   
    conv4_2_output = base_model.get_layer(index=43).output
    conv3_2_output = base_model.get_layer(index=30).output
    conv_score_output = base_model.output

    head_model = skipNet(conv_score_output, conv4_2_output, conv3_2_output, classes)

    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=head_model)

    return model
```

Comment: if you found a reason / solution to this, we'd love to hear.